# Simple Android onTouch Event

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am getting started with android app programming. I am having trouble with detecting any Touch events. Been trying something like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("This works?");
            ImageView aniView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            helpAnimate(aniView, 0);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I dont seem to be hitting the `onTouch` method at all. If anyone can help me with a short tutorial to make anything appear onTouch, I should be able to proceed from there.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you testing this on a real device or the emulator?

Comment: One possible explanation why your event does not trigger might by caused by the fact that you may have implemented OnTouchListener interface globally for your activity and that consumes the event. Is that the case?

Comment: For buttons and most views(like ImageView) you would/could use the onClickListener(View v), if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Another thought I had was to try the Log.i("", "This works"); instead of System.out.println();

Comment: I am using an actual device for this. I found that working with the emulator for touch events is hard. I got an event to run when a button is pushed. It is the touch part that is giving me a hard time. There are too many contracting examples in the interwebs